# All the bones in the imported armature faces the same way

Tags: rigging, armature, .fbx

Okay, so I'm brand new to blender and I can animate and rig basic characters pretty easy. I got the FBX file online of a character model from a video game but when I imported them, they already had an armature but it looked like this... I don't understand why it looks so different from the other basic ones and I have no idea where to start. In all of the tutorials I've watched, I've never come across a model like this.

Also, the model is in pieces, not just one entity. Do I just join them together?

[image: armature of my character]

[image]

In the second picture, I just hid the armature.

Comment: It's not uncommon for armatures that came from other software to have bone all facing the same direction when imported in Blender but the rig should work just fine, even with that. If it really bothers you, you can just go to edit mode and rotate the bones, there is a method you can use to make it faster but it's a bit long to explain (and I'm not sure it's the answer you're looking for too). Also the model being separated into multiple object is a common thing too, people do that to make their work easier but you can merge them with CTRL+J if you want, the rig should still work.

Comment: Thanks! That actually does help. Your right, it really doesnt affect the actual rig. I was kinda weirded out by the fact that the armature looks a lot different than the ones I'm used to seeing in the basic tutorials on youtube.

Comment: As long a s you can still work with it, I guess it's OK. May be there is a way to avoid this while importing but I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I was just acknowledged that there is an option that allows Blender to attempts aligning the bones automatically when importing from FBX :

[image]

If you check that box, Blender will (try to) align the bones so that each parent point towards their children which should be the case for a regular armature. You should try that to see if it solves the problem.

As a side note, it is recommended to leave the bones as they are if you are planning to reexport the model for use in other softwares.

This was tipped to me by [this tutorial by CGDive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLfrrtJNWP8).